# Python converting string of different types of variables into tuple

Tags: python, string, tuples

I was wondering if it's possible to convert a string like this :

```
"0, Hello, [item1, item2]"
```

into this:

```
(0, "Hello", [item1, item2])
```

in python 3. If its possible, how do I do it ?

This is where I'm needing this :

```
A = input("Give me a integer, string and a list\n")
```

Because input always returns a string I can not use the given values in my program.

Comment: is it fixed length? will the last two items always be like that?

Comment: why dont use split??

Comment: split about _ ? @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: @vishes_shell - Not a duplicate. `ast.literal_eval` doesn't work on malformed data, and then only on literals. Not even `eval` would work here.

Comment: @themistoklik No, that was just an example.

Comment: @mu無 item1 and item2 are just variables that are given data. They can be anything.

Comment: If the variables item1,item2 are not known at runtime I don't see how  anything more than simple split,then casting to what you want can help you. Can you make the question more specific?

Comment: @themistoklik I tried to make the question more understandable now. Does that help to understand my problem?

Comment: *and a list* - a list of what? strings, intergers ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Just a list. It may contain any "basic" variables (strings, integers, floats, booleans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the solution the OP wants to achieve, as I supposed `item1` and `item2` are two variables that are already assigned:

```
sample = '0, Hello, [item1, item2]'
item1, item2 = 'A string', True
groups = re.match(r'(\d+),\s?(\w+),\s?(\[(\w+,\s?)*\w+\])', sample)
result = int(a.group(1)), a.group(2), eval(a.group(3))
```

Result:

```
(0, 'Hello', ['A string', True])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution to your problem is to read input separately 3 times. Other than that you can do

```
input = input.split(',')
#cast it or not
number = int(input[0])
string = input[1]
list = ','.join(input[1:])
final = tuple([number,string,list])
```

List holds string contents. Cast them to your appropriate values, or if they're known variables try using `eval()` . Make sure to sanitize input if you do use eval

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
>> import re
>> s = '0, Hello, [item1, item2]'
>> tuple(re.split(',+(?![^\[]*\])', s))
('0', ' Hello', ' [item1, item2]')
```

Comment: It should be `(0, "Hello", [item1, item2])`, not `('0', ' Hello', ' [item1, item2]')`.

Comment: @M.K It can't be that, it's not a valid Python.. `item1` is a string, can't be converted to a variable name. Also `"` and `'` are the same for representing a string.

Comment: Why? `item1` and `item2` are just two variables.

Comment: @MarounMaroun But then the answer to my question would be: "Sorry, it's not possible." And I would accept that. Anyways the question was: "Is it possible? If yes then how to do it?" Sadly what you suggest isn't what I'm looking for...

Comment: @miroreflect You can now use `eval` on `Hello` for example and get its value.

Answer (score -1):

Well, should work like that:

```
import re
a = "0, Hello, [item1, item2]"
b = re.findall("|".join([r"\[.*\]", r"[0-9]", r"[a-zA-Z]+"]), a)
```

returns:

```
['0', 'Hello', '[item1, item2]']
```

Now you have the 3 desired elements and you can split the last element into a list of the items.

```
c = b[2][1:-1].split(", ")
```

Returns:

```
['item1', 'item2']
```

After the last line you can convert the items if required. Like that:

```
[int(a) for a in c]
```

would give you integer representation of your list elements.

Comment: Check the output of what you have written, is it the same as required by the OP ?

Comment: Note that `[item1` and `item2]` are two separated items here.

Comment: Why are you making useless edits, your method is plain wrong.

Comment: got it, missed the last comma :( - too early

Comment: So, solution is now as requested. Needed a coffee to get my eyes open.